# FragmentActivity not calling ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a `ListFragment`. The idea is to use `CursorLoader`. The code for FragmentActivity is

```
public class XYZ extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            XYZFragment list = new XYZFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
}
```

Now I assume that `onActivityCreate` of `XYZFragment` should be called but that is not happening instead I am getting a the below image on the Emulator. I am looking for an explanation as to what is happening and what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean `onActivityCreated`, not `onActivityCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onActivityCreate` to `onActivityCreated` and you should get the expected results.